# Listview header stretched

Tags: android, listview

How can I pull a listview like this?

[image]
Listview has a header is a singer avatar, when pulldown listview, the picture is stretched out.
Pic1 is normal,
pic2 is pulled down.

Comment: you can animate and reduce the width of list.

Comment: @son nt Did you resolved this feature?

Comment: the easiest (but not the cleanest) solution would be to add a touch listener to an imageview above the list. Then you can recognize the touch movement and change the size of the image accordingly. The listview has to be below the image (e.g. relative layout, or linear layout). But this is probs not the best solution ;)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any kind of empty or invisible view.

Basically, you add a view (or layout) to the `ListView` as header using `addHeaderView()`. After that you override the

```
    overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX,
        int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY,
        int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent)
```

method of the `ListView`. You manipulate the height of the view that you added as the header in the `overScrollBy` method by `deltaY` parameter.

Check this library if you want to avoid all the hard work https://github.com/Gnod/ParallaxListView.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so hard to achieve that. You can add transparent empty header with height of your image (in expanded state). Add layout with image under the listView. Your layout will look like this:

```
<FrameLayout>
  <LinearLayout> //layout with your image and controlls
  </LinearLayout>
  <ListView/> //your listView
</FrameLayout>
```

After that you must implement on scroll change listener of your listView. There you must determine is your transparent header on screen and set Y position of controll layout. With this technic you can create defferent behavior of header in list view (parallax effect, fading animation or somthing else)

Answer (score 0):

You can use parallax effect for this[Gnod/ParallaxListView
scal](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Paralloid) and for you need there is a solution by [ManuelPeinado](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado)

Acton bar fading or fade action bar you can check this from [here](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar)

it scale image while scroll list view .i think this is a sutable solution for your question.

Hope this will help you